# double cannot be converted to doubel []

Tags: arrays, double

```
private void calculateProducedEnergy() {
        for (Integer s : mWeatherProfile.getSunshine()) {
            for (Double w : mWeatherProfile.getWeatherConditions()) { 
            mProducedEnergy = s * w * mPvSystem.getEfficiency() * mPvSystem.getPanelSurface();
            }                           
        }
    }
```

Error: double cannot be converted to doubel []
 mProducedEnergy is a double array
 s & w are Arraylist double
mPvSystem.getEfficiency() & mPvSystem.getPanelSurface() are doubles

Comment: Language?  Looks like Java.  Also looks like you need to create a dynamic array and use `.add()` to push a value into the array.  You can't just say `array = value` because that's like saying "make my shopping list milk."  You didn't add milk *to* the shopping list, you made the list *into* milk, which makes no sense.

Comment: It looks like you are assigning `mProducedEnergy` (which is a `double[]`) a value of type `double`.  So the error is expected.  Are you looking to add it in the array?  Or create a new array with this value in it, perhaps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if mProducedEnergy is an array of double, then you cant assign a double value to a double array, you need to provide the index that it goes to.

The following assumes mProducedEnergy is a previously instantiated double[] array in the global scope, which I am assuming because your function does not return anything so you probably have a declaration like

```
private Double[] mProducedEnergy = new Double[..];
```

outside of a function in your code but inside the class

```
private void calculateProducedEnergy() {
    int index = 0;
    for (Integer s : mWeatherProfile.getSunshine()) {
        for (Double w : mWeatherProfile.getWeatherConditions()) { 
            mProducedEnergy[index] = s * w * mPvSystem.getEfficiency() * mPvSystem.getPanelSurface();
            index++;
        }                           
    }
}
```

Comment: This assumes that the array has been instantiated to a non-null value first, which it may not have been.

Comment: you are right, I was just trying to show how you would assign a double value to an array.